# R remove special characters in columnnames

Tags: r, regex, character

I have a bgd dataframe with lots of columns. Now I want to change the names of the columns. I want to remove () and _ like that:

**tBodyAccJerkMag-mean()**  should be renamed to **tBodyAccJerkMag_mean**
This must be done for all columns 
How would I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use 2 `gsub` calls. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `make.names()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`names(yourdf) <- make.names(names(yourdf))`